# How can I access an SVG element embedded in a CSS `background` from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Given this HTML and CSS that embeds an SVG as a `background`:

```
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect id="rect" width="100" height="100" fill="red"><animate attributeName="x" from="0" to="400" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite"/></rect></svg>');
}
```

I want to use JavaScript to access `#rect` like so:

```
// Wait for the SVG to load.
window.onload = function() {
  // ...but this still logs null
  console.log(document.getElementById("rect"));
}
```

But this prints `null` in the console. Is there any way to get a reference to this `<rect>` via JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When loaded as a CSS `<image>` (like through `background-image` but also through `content` and other CSS properties), your SVG document is loaded in an external environment, that scripts don't have access to, just like it is in an HTML `<img>` by the way.

For all that matters you can even forget there is an SVG Document loaded at all here.
If you want to modify the image, you need to edit the URL directly:

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
// rule is a string
const rule = getComputedStyle(box).backgroundImage;
box.style.backgroundImage = rule.replace("red", "blue");
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect id="rect" width="100" height="100" fill="red"><animate attributeName="x" from="0" to="400" dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite"/></rect></svg>');
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```